# Getting an invalid vm error opcode in solidity, any ideas?

Tags: solidity, opcode

I am trying to test this simple contract to remove an address from an array but I keep getting this "invalid opcode" error.

```
contract C {
    address[] addrList;

    function addAddr(address addr) public{
       addrList.push(addr);
    }

    function deleteAddr(address addr)public {

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < addrList.length; i++) {
            if(addr == addrList[i]) {
                for(uint256 j = i; j < addrList.length; j++) 
                    addrList[j] = addrList[j + 1];

                     delete addrList[addrList.length - 1];
                     addrList.length--; // <== This gives Error: Expression has to be an lvalue.
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming because you are iterating variable `j` from `i` to `addrList.length-1`. This makes the `addrList[j+1]` out of index.

You need to iterate `j` from `i` to `addrList.length-2`. This can be achieved by updating the condition to `j < addrList.length-1`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.3;

contract C { 

    address[] addrList;

    function addAddr(address addr) public{
        addrList.push(addr);
    }

    function deleteAddr(address addr) public {

        for(uint256 i = 0; i < addrList.length; i++) {
             if(addr == addrList[i]) {
                 for(uint256 j = i; j < addrList.length-1; j++) {
                     addrList[j] = addrList[j + 1];
                 }
                 //delete addrList[addrList.length - 1]; 
                 addrList.length--;
             }
        }
    }

    function returnList() view public returns (address[] memory) {
        return addrList;
    }

}
```

Also, you do not require to use the delete step as compiler cleans up the memory slots by itself.